# ssrs forward parameter and available values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a drill down report in ssrs. Trying to pass the value of a parameter from parent report to child. Now in child report i already have a set of available values for that parameter. What i am trying to achieve is, when the child report loads the default value should be the one I am passing from the parent report and the report data should get loaded based on that and after the initial load the user can select form the drop down and refresh the report. For me the problem is when the child report is getting loaded its not taking the value of the parameter passed from the parent report.
Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: is the value you are passing in the list of available values in the child report?

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a dummy report that does what you asked for and found that SSRS will just not work - not give an error at all - if you don't have it exactly right.

Here are the steps I followed to make it work.

1. Create the parameter on the parent report and ensure it is set and that you are setting it either at run time or via default.
2. Ensure that the parameter you want to SET exists in the child report and has NO default value (this may not be necessary, but will help with debugging if it goes wrong)
3. Make sure the child report parameter has the the available values for your drop down set and that the one you are passing is there
4. Set up the drill through using the action section of the properties and **Go to report**
5. Specify the drill through report
6. Choose the parameter from the **Name** drop down (the available parameters in the child report WILL be there) and set the Value to **[@ParameterName]**
7. Test

If you don't want a parameter on the parent report and just want to hard code the value you can skip step 1 and change step 6 to just use the value.

Comment: I was able to do that using an extra parameter

Comment: Have you tried with a couple of fresh reports?  Make two new reports and follow these steps.  Make sure you use the square brackets in step 6 as that tripped me up a while back.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the default specific value to the parameter so it will not show you "Select Value" in dropdown list.

Once you send parameter from Parent report it will set the value.